# Prevent Android AlarmManager from stopping when application resumes

Tags: android, alarmmanager, onresume

The code below runs fine when I start the repeating alarm. Then, I press the home screen button of the mobile device to display the home screen. Next, I long press the home screen button and resume the AlarmManager application from the Recent Application List. Once the AlarmManager application resumes, the repeating alarm stops. However, I need the repeating alarm to continue.

What code is needed to prevent the repeating alarm from stopping at resuming?

I am still a very beginner in Android programming. Many thanks for your help and suggestions.

```
//The Activity Code:
//==================
public class AlarmManagerActivity extends Activity {

private AlarmManager alarmManager;
private BroadcastReceiver alarmReceiver;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private int alarmCounter;
private EditText alarmsReceived;

private Handler myHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case 10:
            alarmsReceived.setText(String.valueOf(alarmCounter));
            try {
                Uri soundNotification = RingtoneManager.
                        getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                Ringtone ringTone = RingtoneManager.
                        getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), soundNotification);
                ringTone.play();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    alarmsReceived = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.alarmsReceivedEditText);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.AlarmManager.ALARM_ACTION");
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    alarmReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            alarmCounter++;
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                    0, new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            Notification ntfctn = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
                    "Notification Title", System.currentTimeMillis());
            ntfctn.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Notification Title",
                    "Notification Text", contentIntent);
            notificationManager.notify(0, ntfctn);
            Message msg = myHandler.obtainMessage(10, intent);
            myHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    };
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.AlarmManager.ALARM_ACTION");
    registerReceiver(alarmReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Place code here
}

public void startAlarm(View v) {
    Calendar clndr = Calendar.getInstance();
    clndr.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    clndr.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 1000);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, clndr.
            getTimeInMillis(), 5000, pendingIntent);
}

public void stopAlarm(View v) {
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm canceled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}




//The main.xml:
//=============

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:text="Alarm Counter:">
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:id="@+id/alarmsReceivedEditText"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF">
    </EditText>

</TableRow>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button android:id="@+id/startAlarmButton"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Start Alarm"
        android:onClick="startAlarm" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stopAlarmButton"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Stop Alarm"
        android:onClick="stopAlarm" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a working `startAlarm` you can try:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startAlarm(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when pause your activity use:

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainTabActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent_ = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainTabActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
  cancel();
```

}

and when resume:

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    start();

}
```

and this code for functions start() and cancel() :

```
  public void start() {
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int interval = 10000;

    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 4000, interval, pendingIntent_);
   // Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public void cancel() {
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    manager.cancel(pendingIntent_);
   // Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```